# error TS2339: Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, typescript

I'm using Typescript with AngularJS.
I have a problem with modals using typed definition of jQuery library.
I get the following error: 'error TS2339: Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.'

Version: jQuery library, version 1.10.x / 2.0.x
Definitions: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Code

```
$scope.delete = function (id) {
  Photo.get({id: id}, function(result) {
     $scope.photo = result;
     $('#deletePhotoConfirmation').modal('show');// error line 
  });
};
```

I'm referencing to `jquery.d.ts` in `angular.d.ts`

```
<reference path="../jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
```

and my global vendor reference file looks like:

```
<reference path='../vendor/types/angular/angular.d.ts' />
<reference path='../vendor/types/angular/angular-mocks.d.ts' />
<reference path='../vendor/types/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts' />
```

Comment: $scope.delete = function (id) {
            Photo.get({id: id}, function(result) {
                $scope.photo = result;
                $('#deletePhotoConfirmation').modal('show');  // error line
            });
        };

Comment: I'm referencing to 'jquery.d.ts' in 'angular.d.ts' file: /// <reference path="../jquery/jquery.d.ts" />  and my global vendor reference file looks like: /// <reference path='../vendor/types/angular/angular.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='../vendor/types/angular/angular-mocks.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='../vendor/types/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts' />

Comment: @TomekB please do not post code in comments, edit the question post it there, there is edit link at bottom of question below tags

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53098414/5361964 explains all steps to get rid of this issue

Answer (score 79):

with newer versions of typescript (>v2 i believe):

```
npm install -D @types/bootstrap
```

Edit:
As hughjdavey said in his comment, you also need the following import lines:

```js
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: This worked for me in a project with jquery types also installed - it added to the jQuery interface such that `$(modal-selector).modal('show')` etc compiles fine

Comment: I also had to add `import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";` to my `app.module.ts` otherwise IntelliJ stopped complaining but it still wouldn't compile on command line with the same error. Doesn't matter what you call it (doesn't have to be bootstrap). For absolute clarity, I also have `import * as $ from "jquery";` in the same file which lets me use `$(...)` in my components.

Comment: thank you @hughjdavey!!! for including those specific import statements... i can't believe how obscure this is for how common of a need it must be?!?

Comment: I don't know why but this does not work properly for me...A times it works. But most of the times, it does not work... Do you know why ?  I ran the command and imported `bootstrap.js` in the component ts file but it still fails

Comment: You can avoid polluting your code with unused references to 'bootstrap' if you add "bootstrap" to the "types" property of the "compilerOptions" object in tsconfig.json.

Comment: in my agular 4 project, i was getting this warning with Bootstrap imported as `import 'bootstrap'` while running tests (with karma), and this fix fixed it.

Answer (score 18):

Your problem is caused by the lack of property with name `modal` in the [jquery.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) file.

If you sure that this work in pure JS you can trick with it like this

```
$scope.delete = function (id) {
  Photo.get({id: id}, function(result) {
     $scope.photo = result;
     (<any>$('#deletePhotoConfirmation')).modal('show');
  });
};
```

Also, you can find additional `d.ts` file where this option has already been defined.

Try to consider [this](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery.simplemodal/jquery.simplemodal.d.ts) library that has already had `modal` option

Good Luck!

Comment: I've checked 'jquery.simplemodal.d.ts '. It works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

In my case I had to use

```
npm install -D @types/bootstrap
```

and then I had to import bootstrap

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

but most important step was to **remove** jquery

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

otherwise it was giving me this error:

> TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Answer (score 12):

When I upgrade angular to version 9, I faced this issue.

Here are my solution, I shared for whom concerned.

**Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery'**

```
$('#ManualMinMaxModal').modal('show');
```

change to

```
($('#ManualMinMaxModal') as any).modal('show');
```

And

**Property 'DataTable' does not exist on type 'JQuery'**

```
$('#realTimeTable').DataTable()
```

change to

```
($('#realTimeTable') as any).DataTable()
```

With

```
!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#realTimeTable')
```

change to

```
!($.fn as any).DataTable.isDataTable('#realTimeTable')
```

Updated:

cast to any sometime not work, and finally solution is change declare from `import * as $ from 'jquery'` to `declare var $: any;`

Answer (score 9):

this work for me, i add in first row:

`declare var $ :any;`

this declare `$` type is `any`  ,

Comment: where did u add this

Comment: first row in file that i use that

Answer (score 5):

I could resolve it as follows:

```js
import * as $ from "jquery";

($('#menuModal') as any).modal('toggle');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the typings for Bootstrap DefinitelyTyped

`typings install --global --save dt~bootstrap`

Answer (score 4):

Just add

```
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

in your  `app.module.ts`

And install these packages

npm install @types/jquery --save-dev

npm install @types/bootstrap --save-dev

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Angular 8+ versions :

Not working:

```
$('#deletePhotoConfirmation').modal('show');
```

Instead use this:

```
($('#deletePhotoConfirmation') as any).modal('show');
```

For Import :

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I too had to include both of these imports in order to make my app publishable by angular:

```
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

I added them in the component that was using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `bootstrap.js` to your angular.json?

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

declare var $ :any;

This worked for me.