# How to use Bootstrap 3 Modal in Angular 4 Application?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried every possible solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735396/error-ts2339-property-modal-does-not-exist-on-type-jquery) and I still have this error. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and Angular 4. It happens when I try to show a modal using this:

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look @ this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq). It has a working example and a question for the same with typings and without it. I have used bootstrap and jquery with Angular in that project, you can check the repo too.

In your case you need to add the jquery files

like this in your **angular-cli.json**

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

and then declare in component.`declare var $: any;`

This should work.

**UPDATE**

I went on to create a modal of bootstrap using just jquery in Angular using the steps i mentioned.

It works Check this gh page link - [LINK](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/TestingSPA).

and if you want to check the source code for the same check [LINK](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/TestingSPA).

The answer i posted came from this link this is my page on Angular [LINK](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you haven't added the Bootstrap Javascript files to your Angular project in the correct way. What you should do is to add the files to your `.angular-cli.json` file.

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

[You can read more about it here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-bootstrap-with-angular-c83c3cee3f4a).

### Bonus Tips

Instead of mixing jQuery with Angular, I recommend you to install a library such as `ngx-bootstrap` that have rewritten the Bootstrap components as Angular components instead, it makes it way easier to work with together with the rest of your Angular code.

Resources:

- [ngx-bootstrap Github page](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)
- [Blog Post of how to use Bootstrap with an Angular CLI Project](https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/#4-bootstrap-javascript-components-with-ngx-bootstrap-option-1).

Comment: I added bootstrap from a CDN. But I tried your suggestion of installing with npm and making the changes to the .angular-cli.json file. I still have the same error, what could it be?