# How to close a Bootstrap modal after routerlink redirection with Angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-modal

I am developing my first Angular app. I have a Bootstrap modal with a button which redirects to another section of the app.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" routerLink="/contactar">Contáctenos</button>
```

Problem is, when I get redirected to that section, the modal is somehow still enabled and the whole section is covered with the typical grey transparency behind the modals, and I am not allowed to push any button or do something on this "contactar" section.

I tried to close the modal using jQuery and modal() function, with this method on my component.ts, on the (click) event of the button.

```
closeModal()
{
    let mod=$(".modal")[0];
    mod.modal('hide');
}
```

Like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" (click)="closeModal()" routerLink="/contactar">Contáctenos</button>
```

But it throws the error "Property modal does not exist on type HTML element".

I also tried to do:

```
npm install -D @types/bootstrap
```

Like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735396/error-ts2339-property-modal-does-not-exist-on-type-jquery/41390347)

But it doesn't work.

A solution I found is using a link with href attribute instead of that button. That way the page is loaded again, and then, no modal is activated when I get redirected to the section:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="/contactar">Contáctenos</a>
```

But I don´t like it since it breaks the asynchonous advantages of Angular, and I would like to find a way to close that modal before I get redirected though the routerLink directive.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your button to close the modal when it is clicked:

`data-dismiss="modal"`