# Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm working with Angular 7 and I'm trying to use .modal function of jQuery in my component :

```
show() {
    $('#' + this.id).modal('show');
}
```

But I'm receiving that error... And here is the image:

[image]

I've added also in my `app.module.ts` this line:

> import * as $ from 'jquery';

But issue is still there.

I've found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735396/error-ts2339-property-modal-does-not-exist-on-type-jquery) and followed same steps, but issue is still there.

Here is my `package-lock.json` file, and I've seen there some things related to jquery:

```
 "@types/bootstrap": {
      "version": "4.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-4.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-v1BkpRVgNH9eXE+RtWFP1wh/+SAkPZaxHthS6umqf1sGV0tAvHdPHZpAOB+H74e91ElOxtS56dxbon+lXWk4AQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@types/jquery": "*",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.1"
      }

  "@types/jquery": {
      "version": "3.3.29",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/jquery/-/jquery-3.3.29.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-FhJvBninYD36v3k6c+bVk1DSZwh7B5Dpb/Pyk3HKVsiohn0nhbefZZ+3JXbWQhFyt0MxSl2jRDdGQPHeOHFXrQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@types/sizzle": "*"
      }
    },

"jquery": {
      "version": "3.4.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-3.4.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-36+AdBzCL+y6qjw5Tx7HgzeGCzC81MDDgaUP8ld2zhx58HdqXGoBd+tHdrBMiyjGQs0Hxs/MLZTu/eHNJJuWPw=="
    },
```

If anyone might help that would be great! Thanks !

Comment: Go to your page, open your console and type `console.log($.fn.modal)` and see what it logs.

Comment: @Taplar It says :`console.log($.fn.modal)`
VM26:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:18

Comment: `console.log(jQuery.fn.modal)` then

Comment: @Taplar VM29:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: So it appears that jQuery is not being included on the page in the global scope.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for helping me mate, how could I include it in the global scope? :/

Comment: That would be a question for someone more adept at angular.  I'm just trying to help with some of the starting debugging, :)

Comment: @Taplar thanks a lot for your help! It helped a lot even if it's not related directly to angular, I solved issue by adding manually file called typings.d.ts as in Angular 7 and above it does not coming like in previous versions, and there in that file I added interface JQuery { ... } and everything works now! :)

Comment: Very nice!  Glad you were able to dig and solve it yourself, :)

Comment: @Taplar yeah, I came to an idea to check someone else's project on git, as there must be guys with public repo which must use jquery in their angular project, so I found one of them and digged deep in the project until I found what the heck was causing my problem :D I simply compared our files and I've found that I'm missing complete file, and after that I checked on web and really it says that its not coming anymore in angular 7 + hehhe :)) I hope this answer will be useful for somebody

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue by adding manually file called ***typings.d.ts*** as in Angular 7 and above it does not coming like in previous versions, and there in that file I added `interface JQuery { ... }` and everything works now! :)

```
interface JQuery {
  dataTable: any;
  datepicker: any;
  datetimepicker: any;
  moment: any;
  select2: any;
  DataTable: any;
  iCheck: any;
  animateCss: any;
  actual: any;
  fullscreen: any;
  noUiSlider: any;
  modal: any;
  tab: any;
  multiselect: any;
  spectrum: any;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue and i have done the below steps and it got resolved.

```
# in your terminal paste this
npm install -D @types/bootstrap --save

# put this in your app.module.ts
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

Answer (score -1):

I have run into this same issue. What worked for me simply was installing the official typings for JQuery.

`npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

And then in your `.tsconfig` file find the `"types"` array and insert this like so:

```
"types": [
...
"jquery",
...
]
```

With your `import * as $ from 'jquery';`, you should be good to go.

Comment: I did it before and didn't worked until I created typings.d.ts file and added interface Jquery there..