# How to import Fomantic-UI into an Angular project

Tags: jquery, angular, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

I'm developing an Angular project base on Fomantic-UI framework (that is a fork of Semantic-UI).

I have installed it:

`npm install --save fomantic-ui`

and then I have added the following lines in `angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/fomantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/fomantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js"
]
```

I have also installed types for it with `npm install --save @types/semantic-ui` and, according to [this](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI/issues/1205), they should work fine with Fomantic-UI.

Anyway this seems not to be enough to use functions such as `modal()`, `dropdown()`, `calendar()`, in fact I get error both within my IDE (Webstorm) and during compile:

`TS2339: Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.`

`TS2339: Property 'calendar' does not exist on type 'JQuery<any>'.`

`TS2339: Property 'dropdown' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.`

and so on...

Do you know what is the right way to import Fomantic-UI in my project?

Comment: Nobody knows it...

Answer (score 0):

For Typescript types you need to add some lines into your `tsconfig.json` file to declare those types to your Angular Application.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "semantic-ui"
    ],
    ...
}
```

And also in the `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "semantic-ui"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Same in the test file `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "semantic-ui"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the same errors. What about the import of jQuery that is a dependency of Semantic/Fomantic? Maybe could it be related to the right way to import Semantic/Fomantic?

Comment: This would be stange since when it really needs jquery then it should already downloaded it. You might have to check some dependency versions. Maybe there was something that was changed of the dependencies recently, but not covered.

Comment: But it would be worth a try to download jquery and try to make it running.

Comment: Yes, I have already installed jQuery and its types then added `import * as $ from 'jquery';` in `main.ts` to use `$` within the whole application. But using `dropdown`, `modal`, `calendar` and other Semantic modules with `$` give me those errors...

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it. Give me some time!

Comment: I have tested it and it worked without issues. https://github.com/LingVuDev/FormaticUITest
You might clone it and take a look

Comment: I did clone your project... where did you use `dropdown`, `modal` and other Semantic funcions?

Comment: Ah okay I missed that, let me try.

Comment: Yea sorry, I couldn't solve it. I hope you could find a solution!

Comment: Thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is several issues , first install jquery

[install jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular)

```
npm install jquery — save
```

[error TS2339: Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735396/error-ts2339-property-modal-does-not-exist-on-type-jquery)

according to user [@tucker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639868/tucker)

1. Property `modal` does not exist on type `JQuery`
   install

   `npm install -D @types/bootstrap`

Comment: I know, I have installed it and even its types. But you said to install `@types/bootstrap`. Why?

Comment: its due to one of your error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735396/error-ts2339-property-modal-does-not-exist-on-type-jquery