# Fomantic-UI in Angular project: ".popup is not a function"

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, popup, fomantic-ui

I'm trying to create an Angular + Fomantic-UI playground but I'm experiencing problem in importing Fomantic-UI into the Angular project.

Here is my StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcvmam

As you can see I do import `jquery`, `fomantic-ui-css` and their related typings and I'm trying to use one of the functionalities of Fomantic-UI (popup):

```
$('.bell.icon', this.el.nativeElement)['popup']({
    popup: $('.ui.popup', this.el.nativeElement),
    position: 'bottom right',
    on: 'click'
});
```

```
<i class="large blue bell icon"></i>

<div class="ui popup">
    <div class="ui middle aligned divided list">
        <div class="item" *ngFor="let alert of alerts" [@expandCollapse]>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="header">
                    {{alert.title}}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {{alert.desc}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work: **.popup is not a function**

The same happens with other F-UI modules, such as `modal`, `transition`, `dropdown` and so on.

Can you figure out what is missing to make it working?
If you do you can also answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200120/how-to-import-fomantic-ui-into-an-angular-project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a problem when using fomantic and jquery libraries on stackblitz. I'm not sure why they don't work, but by adding the CDN link in the index.html and using

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

instead of

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

you can use jquery with fomantic's additions in your code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjet1p

I get some errors in your code when running it, but they are outside the scope of this question.